# I want to store a .7z file into specific folder in phone internal storage using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have found a code on stackoverflow,

```
        val data: String = "hello 123"
        val path = this.getExternalFilesDir(null)

        val folder = File(path, "folder1")
        folder.mkdirs()

        println(folder.exists()) // u'll get true

        val file = File(folder, "message.txt")
        file.appendText(data)
```

by using this I was able to achieve this :-

```
// internal storage --> Android /data/com.example.testing123/files/folder 1/message.txt --> hello 123
```

but what I want is:-

```
// internal storage --> Android/data/inside a already available folder (check if folder is there or not, if not then create it) com.heaven.supermaxgame/store a .7z file
```

So please help me, I am new to kotlin, how can I store a 7zip file into a specific folder inside android --> data -->specific folder

Comment: /My/god/please /write/paths/in/the/normal/way.

Comment: println(folder.getAbsolutePath()) println(file.getAbsolutePath())

Comment: please sir can you elaborate i am new

Comment: Something is missing in your question. What's the content of your 7zip? Where does the file come from?

Comment: i have one 7zip file, i need to store that 7zip file as it is inside that folder sir

Comment: i didnt get you?

Comment: You generally do not write access to the app-specific storage of other apps. Please store the file in your own app's storage.

Comment: Learn about "sandboxing". Each folder in `data` represents sandbox of a different app. You can access your own folder and never those belonging to other apps. Not without root access.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
 okay so plz tell me is it possible to paste that file inside android/data/

instead of android/data/"packagefolder"

Comment: No, because you definitely do not have write access there.